# Unistall app with Firebase and re-install re-authenticated with same user Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When uninstall the app and install again, it re-authenticate with the last user.
Can I stop that? I want if you uninstall the app, user clears.

Thank you

Comment: use  `android:allowBackup="false"` application tag in manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add in your app manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        ....
```